# If $A$ is negative-definite, how do you prove $\frac{1}{2}Z^t AZ$ is concave?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, symmetric-matrices

I have these matrices:
$$Z(t)=\begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ u(t) \end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$$
And then, this function:
$$F(t)=\frac{1}{2}Z(t)^tAZ(t)$$

They tell me that $A$ is **negative-definite**. How do you prove that $F(t)$ is concave?

PS: I have tried with $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} F(t)<0$ but I can't finish it.

Comment: are $x$ and $u$ linear?

Comment: I do not have that information. How would it be if they were linear?

Comment: Then it's trivial ($f(x)=x^TAx$ is concave, linear transformations of the input do not impact concavity). If $x$ or $u$ is not linear it's more complex (forget about $u$ and consider $A=1$ to get $F(t) = -0.5x(t)^2$. For concavity you need $F''(t) = -(x'(t))^2-x(t)x''(t) \leq 0$.